# How to skip selected url while mirroring site with wget

Tags: wget

I have the following problem. I need to mirror password protected site. Sounds like simple task:

```
wget -m -k -K -E --cookies=on --keep-session-cookies --load-cookies=myCookies.txt http://mysite.com
```

in myCookies.txt I am keeping proper session cookie. This works until wget come accross logout page - then session is invalidated and, effectively, further mirroring is usless.

W tried to add `--reject` option, but it works only with file types - I can block only html file download or swf file download, I can't say

```
--reject http://mysite.com/*.php?type=Logout*
```

Any ideas how to skip certain URLs in wget? Maybe there is other tool that can do the job (must work on MS Windows).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What if you *first* download (or even just `touch`) the logout page, and then

```
wget --no-clobber --your-original-arguments
```

This should skip the logout page, as it has already been downloaded

(Disclaimer: I didn't try this myself)

Comment: +1; I did `touch page.php?type=Logout` then `wget --no-clobber http://tkos.co.il/page.php?type=Logout` and got `File 'page.php?type=Logout' already there; not retrieving.`

Comment: It is quite easy to achieve the same with HTTrack: httrack.exe http://mysite.com --mirror --cookies=1 -*Logout* assuming that cookies are in the cookies.txt file

Answer (score 3):

I have also encountered this problem and later solved it like this: "--reject-regex logout", more:[wget-devTips](https://github.com/mythkiven/mkPlan/blob/master/devTips/wget.md)

Comment: Doesn't this still make the HTTP request to the logout page thereby expiring the cookie? Edit: Ah, it works. I was using just --reject (instead of --reject-regex). Just --reject doesn't seem to work (it still makes HTTP request) but --reject-regex works.